# how to change $("#button").one("click", first ); to $("#button").one("click",second); by clicking on a button

Tags: javascript

**index.html :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1-10-1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1-9-2.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button1").click(function(){
        $("#div").css("background","red");

        //some code here

    });
});
$(function (){
    function first(){
        $("#div").css("background","red");
        $(this).one("click",second);
    }
    function second(){
        $("#div").css("background","blue");
        $(this).one("click",first);
    }
    $("#button2").one("click",first);
});

</script>

</head>
<body>
<input type="button" id="button1" value="button1"></input>
<input type="button" id="button2" value="button2"></input>
<div id="div">some text</div>
</body>
</html>
```

what should i put in **some code here** to when i click on button1 ,

**$("#button2").one("click",first);** become to **$("#button2").one("click",second);**

Comment: what is the problem with your code? Is it working or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `unbind` existing `one` click event and set a new `one`

```
$("#button2").unbind("click");  
$("#button2").one("click",second);
```

This should unbind first one and bind second one.

```
$("#button1").click(function(){
    $("#div").css("background","red");
    $("#button2").unbind("click");  
    $("#button2").one("click",second);
});
```

Comment: furthermore i have to put function first and second out of   **$(function (){ });**